# how do i add checkbox in simple adapter

Tags: android

This is my code below which used simple adapter in the grid view. Every thing  is work fine but i want to add checkbox in my code so what do i do? how i add checkbox in my simple adapter? I  my code check if file is directory show icon other wise show images. I just want to add checkbox so user select checkbox and delete checkbox selected multiple images

```
 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
 GridView gridView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),"photos");
photos.mkdirs();

File root1 = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.folder/files/");

 currentParent = root1;
currentFiles = root1.listFiles();

  currentFilePath = new String[currentFiles.length];
  int count = 0;

 for(File f:currentFiles)
 {   
currentFilePath[count] = f.getAbsolutePath();
 count++;
}


 gridView =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
position,long id) {


 if(currentFiles[position].isDirectory())
 {
    root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample.folder
   /files/"+FileName(currentFilePath[position])+"/");

    Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");

    currentFiles = root.listFiles();

    inflateListView(currentFiles);
 }
else if(currentFiles[position].isFile())
{
      inflateListView(currentFiles);    
           }

 private void inflateListView(File[] files){

List<Map<String,Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
{       
Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

if(files[i].isDirectory())
{
    listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
}
else
{
    listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.file);
}

listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName());
listItems.add(listItem);
}

simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listItems,R.layout.line,new String[] 
{"icon","fileName"},new int[]{R.id.icon,R.id.file_name});
 gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Include a checkbox view in your `R.layout.line.xml`. Then you have to extend ArrayAdapter class (not using SimpleAdapter) to override the `getView()` method, something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox);
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thnx but how i exted array adapter class? my code is all above so tell me how i extend??

Comment: I would suggest you to master some basics of Java on how to extend a class first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom adapter for the same.Filling gridview using SimpleAdapter won't do.

Comment: but how? how i use custom adapter according to my code? im using  List<Map<String,Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

Comment: Extend the BaseAdapter from your custom adapter and pass the Arraylist into your adapter constructor for fetching the data e.g.

`public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> myobj;
  public MyAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> myobj) {
                this.myobj=myobj;
   mContext = c;
  }`
and finally override the getview() method